# Should you use ODBC or Registry Entry for data connections?

Tags: odbc

I support a group of developers that are telling me to setup a registry entry for an application that they made in asp.net to connect to our SQL backend. Would it not be better to do this from an ODBC connection? Is this lazy programming or is this common practice?

If all their connections are in registry entries how will I be able to spin up the DRP site in case we have an issue? Right now we replicate the content across and it would be a heck of a lot easier if the DB connections were in ODBC instead of having to redo all these registry entries. (there are multiple apps doing this).

Please fill me in. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are they not using the web.config to store connection strings? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx

Comment: This is what I was thinking. I am not sure. I thought that, that would be the better way no?

Comment: There is no reason to store this information in the registry. Storing connection strings in the registry goes back to the COM+/ASP Classic days, like 10+ years ago. The Windows registry is a mess and should be avoided whenever possible.